# Showing email in the browser: security risks

Tags: email, security, html-email

We have a corporate website that receives external email, processes them, and shows them in the browser to the user. We will be showing the emails in HTML format if they are available in this format. However, this basically means that we will be showing user-generated HTML code (you could send any HTML in an email, as far as I know).

What are the security risks here? What steps to take in order to minimize these risks?

I can currently think of:

- Removing all javascript
- Perhaps removing external CSS? Not sure if this is a security risk
- Not loading images (to limit tracking... not sure if this poses a security risk or just a privacy risk)

Would that be all? Removing HTML tags is always error prone so I am wondering if there is a better way to somehow disable external scripts when displaying e-mail?

Comment: You could snap the email as a image and display that otherwise you have a multitude of possibilities that can cause you issues. Though I have not used this you may find https://htmlcsstoimage.com interesting.

Comment: Thanks but that would be very detrimental to the user experience (bandwidth usage, unable to copy text, unable to open links, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The security risks are, as far as I know, the same as with Cross-Site-Scripting (XSS).
OWASP describes the risks as following:

> XSS can cause a variety of problems for the end user that range in severity from an annoyance to complete account compromise. The most severe XSS attacks involve disclosure of the user’s session cookie, allowing an attacker to hijack the user’s session and take over the account. Other damaging attacks include the disclosure of end user files, installation of Trojan horse programs, redirect the user to some other page or site, or modify presentation of content. An XSS vulnerability allowing an attacker to modify a press release or news item could affect a company’s stock price or lessen consumer confidence.

[Source](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)#XSS_Attack_Consequences)

Defending against it must be with layers of defense, such as but not limited to:

- Sanitizing the HTML with something like [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify).
- Making use of HTTP only cookies for security sensitive cookies so they can't be read from JavaScript. [Source](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly#Mitigating_the_Most_Common_XSS_attack_using_HttpOnly)
- Adding a Content Security Policy so the browser only trusts scripts from domains you tell it to trust. [Source](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Content_Security_Policy_Cheat_Sheet.md)

Depending on your requirements it might also be possible to load the email content into a [sandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) iframe, as an additional security measurement. This can be done like this:

```
var sanitizedHTML = DOMPurify('<div>...</div>');
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
iframe.srcdoc = sanitizedHTML;
```